# After upgrading to Mavericks, two-finger right-clicking in Chrome doesn't work

Tags: macos, google-chrome, trackpad

I upgraded my rMBP to Mavericks recently and since then, I'm not able to right-click in Chrome using the trackpad. I can click on menu bars and things like that but not within the actual webpage display window that it renders.

When changing the gesture to the bottom right click, it still doesn't work.

Any workarounds?

Comment: I think I was able to fix this my unsyncing my Chrome profile's extensions and a few other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. The solution for me was to uninstall Chrome extension Smooth Gestures.

Which is a shame, because I love that extension, because it makes managing tabs a lot easier if you use a mouse.